# Force show.bind execution

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a table with data, and i want view to check show.bind statement when the event is fired from another view. The problem is that the event is not changing any data in the current view.

foo.html:

```
 <tr repeat.for="entity of viewData.entities">
  ...
    <p if.bind="$parent.canBeRemoved(entity.id)">
     canBeRemoved
    </p>
 ...
 </tr>
```

I'm receiving the event with EventAggregator and i want it to force refresh on the array. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use the `signal` binding behavior

The best way to handle this is to send a signal through the signal binding behavior.

**template.html**

```
<tr repeat.for="entity of viewData.entities">
  ...
  <p if.bind="$parent.canBeRemoved(entity.id) & signal:'update-view'">
    canBeRemoved
  </p>
  ...
</tr>
```

**viewModel.ts**

```
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

// grab a reference to the signaler
constructor(signaler: BindingSignaler) {
    this.signaler = signaler;
}

// and fire the signal event bound in your view
// whenever the event is handled
respondToEvent(event) {
    // do eventy things
    this.signaler.signal('update-view');
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what i had in mind, works perfectly. Thank You :)

Comment: now

   import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

Comment: Don't reject the edit guys, `BindingSignaler` was moved as noted by kernowcode and the answer should be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a getter function. For instance:

JS

```
export class Entity {

    //@computedFrom('property1', 'property2')
    get canBeRemoved() {
       //your magic here
       //return true or false;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
 <tr repeat.for="entity of viewData.entities">
  ...
    <p if.bind="entity.canBeRemoved">
     canBeRemoved
    </p>
 ...
 </tr>
```