# Aurelia array observation doesn't react on array[index] = newItem

Tags: aurelia

I use surprised why my repeat.for binding doesn't react on array change. Then I found out Aurelia array observation doesn't react on array[index] = newItem.

This is confirmed when I read the spec
https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/master/test/array-observation.spec.js

The array observation only reacts on methods pop/push/reverse/shift/sort/splice/unshift. Replacing the whole array works too.

I can fix my issue with `splice` instead of using `array[index] = newItem`;

But I would like to know is it technically too difficult to react on `array[index] = newItem` for Aurelia array observation?

Comment: it's not difficult, you just need signal binding behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38640748/3715792

Comment: thx @kici, that would help. I need to remember to signal it every time I use `arr[i] = newItem`. Would like to see Aurelia support this natively in future.

Comment: I tried signal, it doesn't work on repeat.for binding but works on other bindings. Don't know is this designed behaviour.

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for your question, since you're not really asking for a solution to your problem but rather for an extra feature in the Aurelia framework. Why not submit a feature request on their Github?

Comment: @FredKleuver thx, will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is offcially unsupported in Aurelia.

https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/509